# JSON transformation with transpose

Tags: groovy

Source JSON:

```
{
    "kind": "analytics#mcfData",
    "containsSampledData": false,
    "columnHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "mcf:conversionDate",
            "columnType": "DIMENSION",
            "dataType": "STRING"
        },
        {
            "name": "mcf:source",
            "columnType": "DIMENSION",
            "dataType": "STRING"
        },
        {
            "name": "mcf:assistedConversions",
            "columnType": "METRIC",
            "dataType": "INTEGER"
        },
        {
            "name": "mcf:lastInteractionConversions",
            "columnType": "METRIC",
            "dataType": "INTEGER"
        }
    ],
    "totalsForAllResults": {
        "mcf:assistedConversions": "62435",
        "mcf:lastInteractionConversions": "156469"
    },
    "rows": [
        [
            {
                "primitiveValue": "20210501"
            },
            {
                "primitiveValue": "Arena"
            },
            {
                "primitiveValue": "30604"
            },
            {
                "primitiveValue": "75593"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "primitiveValue": "20210502"
            },
            {
                "primitiveValue": "Arena"
            },
            {
                "primitiveValue": "31831"
            },
            {
                "primitiveValue": "80876"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Expected:

```
[
  {
    "report_date": "2021-05-01",
    "metric_name": "mcf:assistedConversions",
    "metric_value": "30604"
  },
  {
    "report_date": "2021-05-01",
    "metric_name": "mcf:lastInteractionConversions",
    "metric_value": "75593"
  },
  {
    "report_date": "2021-05-02",
    "metric_name": "mcf:assistedConversions",
    "metric_value": "31831"
  },
  {
    "report_date": "2021-05-02",
    "metric_name": "mcf:lastInteractionConversions",
    "metric_value": "80876"
  }
]
```

What I need from source JSON:

1. Loop through elements in `rows` array
2. Match these elements with date and metric_names:

- in `columnHeaders` ignore elements with `columnType` = `DIMENSION` except `mcf:conversionDate`
- take all elements where `columnType` = `METRIC`.

Elements in `rows` array ordered by `columnHeaders`.

My attempt:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText('')

def headers = json.columnHeaders

def result = json.rows.collectMany{
            [headers, it].transpose().collect{ h, v ->
                [
                 metric_name: h.name,
                 metric_value: v
                ]
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:conversionDate",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "20210501"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:source",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "Arena"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:assistedConversions",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "30604"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:lastInteractionConversions",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "75593"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:conversionDate",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "20210502"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:source",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "Arena"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:assistedConversions",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "31831"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric_name": "mcf:lastInteractionConversions",
        "metric_value": {
            "primitiveValue": "80876"
        }
    }
]
```

How to add `report_date` as described above? It stores inside `mcf:conversionDate`. And get rid off nested json in `metric_value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
def headers = json.columnHeaders

def result = json.rows.collect{
    /* transform each row to a map like this:
        "mcf:conversionDate": "20210502",
        "mcf:source": "Arena",
        "mcf:assistedConversions": "31831",
        "mcf:lastInteractionConversions": "80876"
    */
    [headers, it].transpose().collectEntries{h,v-> 
        [
            h.name,
            v.primitiveValue
        ]
    }
}.collectMany{map->
    def date = map.remove("mcf:conversionDate") //get date and remove from map
    map.findAll{k,v-> k in ["mcf:assistedConversions","mcf:lastInteractionConversions"] }
        .collect{k,v->
            [
                report_date:  date,
                metric_name:  k,
                metric_value: v,
            ]
        }
}


println (new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(result).toPrettyString())
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if instead `mcf:source` there will be `mcf:medium`? Or even both of them.  I can't hardcode it like `map.remove(...)`, because I don't know what exactly `DIMENSION` JSON can contain. 
Main goal - remove all possible elements with `columnType` = `DIMENSION` except `mcf:conversionDate` which will be used as report_date.

Comment: ok. use for example `map.findAll{k,v-> k in ["mcf:assistedConversions","mcf:lastInteractionConversions"] }` to keep only keys you need. or any other expression to filter out unnecessary keys.